# Data loss after compressing geodatabase in ArcSDE

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

I suffer sometimes from data loss after compressing ArcSDE geodatabase, this  geodatabase contains versioned feature classes, so the compressing script reconciles and compress the geodatabase:

```
# Execute the ReconcileVersions tool.
arcpy.ReconcileVersions_management(db_path, "ALL_VERSIONS", "sde.DEFAULT", versionList, "LOCK_ACQUIRED", "NO_ABORT", "BY_OBJECT", "FAVOR_TARGET_VERSION", "POST", "DELETE_VERSION", "c:/reconcilelog.txt")

# Run the compress tool.
arcpy.Compress_management(db_path)
```

it seems that the main reason is a bad use of `ReconcileVersions_management`, what are the parameters recommanded ? and how i can test if data loss would happen again ?

the geodatabase is based on ArcSDE 10.1 and Postgre SQL 9.0.5.

Comment: Please define "accidental data loss" -- what *exactly* is happening?

Comment: i make edits normally , so when the database gets slowing, i run the compacting script, sometimes i i can have nothing lost, but sometimes i can have some data loss, i've tried to find a logical reason , but i have found nothing.

Comment: What does "data loss" mean to you?  Note that *compressing* a versioned geodatabase is *not* the same as *compacting* a file geodatabase.

Comment: Are you losing data from the sde.Default or from a child version (i.e. edits in a child version do not appear in sde.Default after the `ReconcileVersions_management`)?

Comment: @JayCummins yes i think this what happens, so `ReconcileVersions_management` delete child version so the changes are deleted too. can you see what's missing in my code above, or what could be wrong ?

Comment: @Vince yes you're right i confused compressing and compacting ,i meant compressing the database, i corrected the question, thanks

Comment: With batch reconcile it is quite possible to *ask* to have your data discarded.  While it might qualify as "accidental data loss", it's not a result of software failure or server performance.

Comment: i have deleted 'accidental' from question, but do you think the solution is to change `reconcile` parameters ,but how i could test if the data loss still exist or not ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the ArcPy tool, but if you say `NO_ABORT` and `FAVOR_TARGET_VERSION` (in your case 'DEFAULT')...I think you have effectively instructed the tool to "ignore the conflicts" and take what is in DEFAULT. So you would "lose" data whenever a conflict occurs.  Additionally, you defined your "conflict" as "BY_OBJECT" so even if the same feature had different modified attributes...it's still a conflict. If you go "BY_ATTRIBUTE", you are only conflicted when the same attribute is modified.

Comment: You probably want to do some manual reconcile/compress operations until you can reproduce this issue, and then figure out what would be necessary to ensure data retention (changing parameters is a start, but knowing *why* the parameters are appropriate for your needs is better).

Comment: thanks a lot JayCummins and Vince, i will follow your advices to change to the correct parameters, and i wish confirm the solution with some tests.

Comment: You said you would follow up on this based on received comments. Did you ever manage to find the solution? If **yes**, please, post it as an answer. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer. Let me know about the answer, I will upvote it. If, **no** edit Q to include info from comments and results from tests made based on them. Tks.